# How to create a basic yet useful USB toolbox with a selection screen?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, liveusb

I'm an EasyTech at Staples, and I had an idea on how to make my job easier and make me work more efficiently on computers.

My idea is to create a USB toolbox. Similar to what the company provides us. But instead I want to customize it a tad.

What I want exactly is to put ISOs of multiple operating systems onto a decent sized flash drive (Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10) and a few utilities such as a bootable/live version of GParted, perhaps Windows PE, and maybe a regular Linux distro for the heck of it.

What I need is to be able to plug the flash drive in the computer (with all these files/tools on the drive) and be able to choose what I want to use from a list on boot. Kind of like how the BIOS/UEFI allows you to choose from a list of boot devices, I'm looking to create a list of options/tools to choose from for each of these tools/utilities. I'm curious as to how I'd do this, and what programming language(s) I'd need to learn to do this.

Are there any guides or tutorials on how to do this? Any resources would be awesome! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PenDrive Linux has several tools for that purpose. (Under Windows)

1. YUMI - can put Linux Live CD onto USB drive, boot to Windows installation ISO, boot to different tools such as password reset, partition maintenance, and boot to ISO in general. Installer also offer download links to some of the tools.
2. Universal USB Installer - make Linux Live CD and optionally create persistence file that persist across boots.

Ref:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

Comment: Btw that is assuming you can use outside software at your workplace. Many companies would place restrictions on what software you can use. But for personal use these tools come very handy.

Comment: While I'm not able to give specifics for fear of jeopardizing my job, I'll say that my intentions are fine. Really I just want a flash drive for OS restores/installs, without needing multiple flash drives. And while the company provides us with OS installers, it doesn't provide us with all of them. Some people may want/need a more specific version and architecture of Windows.

Comment: Just tried out YUMI.  It's great! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an isostick, a great hardware solution with swappable SD cards.

Or try this utility.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/WinSetupFromUSB.shtml